# Ampersand in HTML form gets converted to %26 after HTML POST

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form. The SSID and password filed are of "type=text". After I fill up the form with an **Ampersand** [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l14VD.png), and submit it and later reload it, the ampersand gets [converted to **%26**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcrPl.png).

Here, I am saving all the information after the form submits and in the event of page reload same saved values are used to display the form fields.

My question is how can I get the ampersand and not **%26** after page submits and reload.

Comment: The `&` is used as separator when the contents of the form is sent to the server. `...?ssid=RTSR%26D&password=3EE3E5C179&port=7882` If the `&` weren't converted, it would screw up the key-value pair format. Just replace it on the backend.

Comment: Could you show the code you have for loading the form with information in?

Comment: <form method="post"><div><label>%s</label><input type="text" name="%s" value="%s"></div><div><label>%s</label><input type="text" name="%s" value="%s"></div><div><label>%s</label><input type="text" name="%s" value="%d"/></div>....This is the form part of the code. I have this HTML file in the RAM of microprocessor from which it is loaded and after the submit I save all the information in the flash and later if the page is loaded previous information are displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my comment was nonsense, I deleted it. You must [escape the field](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before submitting the form, for example "onchange" of the field (don't forget to return true in the method).

```
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("the-field").value)
```

Here's a short [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunnar/nzfpqkd8/).

...and sorry for micro editing: The other way is [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), so in the form field it's ampersand again.

Comment: thanks, the second way of decodeURIComponent worked. :)